# why my google app engine has domain name 'my-project.df.r.appspot.com'?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have Google App Engine enabled in a Google Cloud project `my-project`, 
the App Engine's URL is `my-project.appspot.com` by default, which is fine.
However, I found sometimes it becomes `my-project.df.r.appspot.com` (in my App Engine console), which makes my app engine project using a completely different host name internally.

Does anybody know what's going on here? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: one thing that is promising, existing services will not be forced to update: "Since the ID is optional for existing apps, you don't need to update URLs or make other changes once the region ID is available for your existing apps."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you seen this page yet?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed

There are several ways you can target different versions & services within a single GCP project.

However, most of them spell out `-dot-` instead of using an actual `.` and most of them have `MY_PROJECT_ID` as the thing before `.appspot.com`.

do you have multiple services or versions running in your environment?

EDIT - I found this in the Appengine Flex release notes:

> App Engine is changing the URLs that you use to send requests to your apps. You can now include a region ID to help Google route your requests more efficiently and reliably. For example, an app can receive requests at https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com. This new URL is optional for existing apps, and will soon be required for all new apps.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/release-notes

I'm not seeing this happen to my flex service, but I am seeing it happen to my custom-runtime service. Is yours either of these?

Comment: I do have 1 service with multiple versions, 100% of the traffic go to the latest version. however, I'm not trying to target one specific version.

Comment: is your service an appending-flex service or a custom runtime? see my edit

Comment: thanks Alex. mine one is a standard GAE.  thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

As Alex mentioned, the **App Engine** is changing the URLs that you use to send requests to your apps. According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/release-notes#december_9_2019) documentation, these URLs can now include a **region ID**:

```
https://<PROJECT-ID>.<REGION-ID>.r.appspot.com
```

According to the release notes:

> This new URL is optional for existing apps, and will **soon** be required
>   for all new apps.

---

As I understand, this transition is yet to complete and the backward compatible changes are forthcoming.