# Google App engine displaying incorrect App URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a sample Java Spring Boot application from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/springboot-helloworld) on Google App Engine. I am using the command `mvn appengine:deploy` to deploy the web application.

The application deployment shows success and I am able to access to application using the URL - https://rml-product-development.appspot.com/

However, the app engine console display incorrect URL - Screenshot below:

[image: App Engine Screen]

As it can be seen, it adds `wl.r` in the URL - If I try to ping the URL, there is no IP address mapped to it. Why is this the case? Is it a Bug in GCP?

Comment: Might be similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077636/why-my-google-app-engine-has-domain-name-my-project-df-r-appspot-com

Answer (score 0):

There was an [update earlier in 2020](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/release-notes#February_11_2020). Now, the region is added in the URL of App Engine. It's not mandatory but it's maybe an opening to a multi-region support of App Engine (in the future, I don't know).

In addition, there is no dedicated IP to this URL. There a is pool of URL which listen this URL and the request is routed according with the host called (such as a CNAME record).

No bug, just a feature!